# Connect smartphone to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, smartphone

I've come across this link a while ago:
https://lightsaber.withgoogle.com

I thought it was really cool, the ability to connect your phone to a website and let it control certain things. And just now I found this link: http://www.pauljobard.com/#!/ 
it implements the phone connect option too (if you go to 'experience my work').

I'm considering of experimenting a little something with this for my portfolio website, but I have no idea where to start; can someone give me a push in the right direction? What is this 'function' called? Is it very hard?

to be more specific what I want to use this for: I want the user to be able to drag along a screen and pan and rotate a 3D object that way (I'm a 3d artist).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a link at [Hammerjs](https://hammerjs.github.io/jsdoc/index.html), this allows you to capture your phone's accelerometer and gyroscope data, it's fairly quick to get up and running.

In terms of connecting up a phone to your desktop via a web app, it's a little more work, take a look at this [article](http://www.cykod.com/2011-08-using-nodejs-and-your-phone-to-control-a-browser-game) on establishing a connection with a node server as well at this [article](http://artandlogic.com/2013/06/phone-to-browser-html5-gaming-using-node-js-and-socket-io/) which goes into a little more detail and it should point you in the right direction.